# How to bind angular async data to child component input property

Tags: angular, asynchronous

Hello I'm new to angular and try to figure out how to bind delayed data from view to child component property, I have tried with different *ngIf | bind options without result yet, please find below what seems to be relevant code (please feel free to ask for more code if necessary):

app.component.html :

```
<!-- Toolbar -->
<div class="toolbar" role="banner">
  <span>Welcome to {{ title }}!</span>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>

<div class="content" role="main">

    <app-post-list-component [posts]="getPosts()"></app-post-list-component>

</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { POSTS } from './data/post-data';
import { Post } from './model/post';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AngularPostSample';

  getPosts(): Promise<Post[]>{
    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(
          () => {
            resolve(POSTS);
          },
          0
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

post-list-component.component.html :

```
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h2>POSTS</h2>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <app-post-list-item-component
            *ngFor="let post of posts"
            [post]="post"
          ></app-post-list-item-component>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

post-list-component.component.ts :

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../model/post';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list-component',
  templateUrl: './post-list-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list-component.component.scss']
})
export class PostListComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() posts: Post[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

post-list-item-component.component.html :

```
<li [ngClass]="{
    'list-group-item':true,
    'list-group-item-success': post.loveIts > 2,
    'list-group-item-danger': post.loveIts < 0
}">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div
          style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:red;"
          *ngIf="post.loveIts < -2"
        ></div>
        <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        {{ post.created_at | date: "short"}}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        {{ post.content }}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onLoveIt()">Love it!</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onDontLoveIt()">Don't love it!</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        Popularity : {{ post.loveIts }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

post-list-item-component.component.ts :

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../model/post';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list-item-component',
  templateUrl: './post-list-item-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list-item-component.component.scss']
})
export class PostListItemComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() post: Post;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onLoveIt(): void{
    this.post.loveIts++;
  }

  onDontLoveIt(): void{
    this.post.loveIts--;
  }

}
```

post.ts :

```
export class Post {
  title: string;
  content: string;
  loveIts: number;
  created_at: Date;

  constructor(title: string, content: string) {
    this.title = title;
    this.content = content;
    this.loveIts = 0;
    this.created_at = new Date();
  }
}
```

post-data.ts :

```
import { Post } from '../model/post';

export const POSTS: Post[] = [
  new Post('Mon premier post', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'),
  {
    title: 'Mon deuxième post',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
    loveIts: 0,
    created_at: new Date()
  },
  {
    title: 'Mon troisième post',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam pulvinar',
    loveIts: 0,
    created_at: new Date()
  }
];
```

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? Do you get any error or does it not render anything?

Comment: Do you receive posts in the child component with @Input() posts: []; decorator?

Comment: I have the decorator @Input() posts: Post[]; and I don't have any error but post items are not rendered

Comment: Instead of posting code for 3 different components, I'd suggest making a minimal reproducible example that shows the problem you're having. At the very least explain what exactly isn't working with your code or include any error messages you might be getting.

Comment: because getPosts() method is returning Promise instead of an actual array in the app component, that why in the post list component you have Promise instead of an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted the TypeScript files of your components I'm not sure that this answer solves your problem entirely. But it might be that you still need to specify the  [@Input() decorators](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) in the child components' TS classes before you can use them in the component's template, e.g.

```
@Input() public posts: Array<any>;
```

**Update**

After your edit [I created an example that works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64151782?file=src/app/app.component.ts). The problems were that you did not resolve the promise you passed into your child component, which means the child doesn't know how to handle it. Additionally, when you call `getPosts()` directly in your template, Angular will call it in every cycle thus aggregating the method's return values.
I added a constructor for the `AppComponent` class definition, that will wait on the promise to resolve and put the return values into a class property which is then passed into the child component.
Hope this solves your question.

Comment: I have updated my post with almost everything thanks for your reply

Comment: Maybe this comes in handy farther down the road: [Why you should never use function calls in Angular template expressions](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496)

Answer (score 0):

Just delay the initialization of child component with *ngIf and assign the Promise data in the parent component

```
<div *ngIf="allPosts">
    <app-post-list-component [posts]="allPosts"></app-post-list-component>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this but is not working, I don't know if that is relevant but I'm using function getPosts() instead of property...

Comment: just resolve posts instead of returning Promise object

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve Promise in the parent component and pass resolved posts to the child

```
<app-post-list-component [posts]="POSTARRAY"></app-post-list-component>
```

Or resolve them in the child component, instead of:

```
@Input() posts: Post[];
```

do

```
@Input() posts: Promise<Post[]>;
```

and then posts.then(posts => { // assign to your child posts field ...})